# Why type error on object which merged with object spread

Tags: flowtype

I have a type of entity object like `User` and I want to create factory  function which have default value.

Like below but `createUser1` would be raise error, while redundant looking `createUser2` would no error. Why?

```
export type User = {|
  name: ?string
|};

// error
export const createUser1 = (values: User): User => {
  return {
    name: 'john',
    ...values
  }
}

// no error
export const createUser2 = (values: User): User => {
  return {
    ...{
      name: 'john',
    },
    ...values
  }
}
```

Reproduced example on [Try Flow (v0.104.0)](https://flow.org/try/#0KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcCqBnYU4F44DeAPgFBxwB2AhgLbABccA-BjFAJYUDmJRAvgG4SJAPQi42KNBKhIsOAGMIFVoqjAqMYJmwBGPHAAUANyoAbAK7AMjHVACUtrDlwA+QmTjqYFqBQ-k5NR0jADkAFYQABYUoQA0nuQAdCmmltaefCRZouIUEBJQUlAy4NDwSioV6prazgBMBibmVjbozo7t2HjuBJ7evv59gXApScMjlLQMcBHRsQkjfIuBY2mtmdkkQA)

Comment: Unforghtunately I can't explain why, but it seems there's a third variant without an error:

https://flow.org/try/#0KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcCqBnYU4F44DeAPgFBxwB2AhgLbABccA-BjFAJYUDmJRAvgG4SJAPQi42KNBKhIsOAGMIFVoqjAqMYJmwBGPHAAUANyoAbAK7AMjHVACUtrDlwA+QmTjqYFqBQ-k5NR0jIYA5ABWEAAWFGGMLGycXPYANJ7kAHTZppbWnnwkhaLiFBASUFJQMuDQ8Eoq9eqa2s4ATAYm5lY26M6Ofdh47gSe3r7+o4Fw2ZlT05S0DHCRMXHp03wbgbO5PQVFJEA

Answer (score 0):

This behavior was fixed on Flow v0.111.0 so this is likely a bug!